# How to extract nth URL from string using regex?

Tags: regex, kotlin

I wanted to extract second URL using regex, I cant use any other thing, So far I have managed to extract all URLs from the string using a regex but its just giving out the first URL.

```
fun main() {
    var text = "hello world https://www.google.com hello world https://www.stackoverflow.com hello world https://www.test.com"
    var regex = """((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?)"""
    println(performRegex(text, regex))
}

private fun performRegex(text: String?, regex: String?): String? {
    val regexPattern = Regex("""$regex""")
    return regexPattern.find(text.toString())?.value
}
```

Current Output: https://www.google.com

Expected Output: https://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Try using findAll and get the second item.

Comment: Can it be done without code changes. The code is just for demonstration. It needs to be handled just with Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```kotlin
private fun performRegex(text: String?, regex: String?): String? {
    val regexPattern = Regex("""$regex""")
    val matchList = regexPattern.findAll(text.toString()).map{it.value}.toList() 
    return if (matchList.size >= 2) matchList[1] else null
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var text = "hello world https://www.google.com hello world https://www.stackoverflow.com hello world https://w...content-available-to-author-only...t.com"
    var regex = """(?:https?|ftp)://\S+"""
    println(performRegex(text, regex))
}
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/kC9gmZ).

The regex is `(?:https?|ftp)://\S+`, it matches `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://` and then any one or more non-whitespace chars.

The `val matchList = regexPattern.findAll(text.toString()).map{it.value}.toList()`  part finds all matches and maps the results to a list of strings.

The `return if (matchList.size >= 2) matchList[1] else null` part returns the second match found if the match list size is two or more, else, it returns `null`.

Comment: The code is just for demonstration. I cant change the code.It  needs to be handled only with Regex

Comment: @VaibhavChopade You will have to modify the code just because a regex is a string that defines the rules, what to match. How many matches to search for is code responsibility. `(?:http|ftp)s?://\S++.*?((?:http|ftp)s?://\S+)` [can work for you](https://regex101.com/r/0MURdb/1/), but you still need to get Group 1 value.

Comment: @VaibhavChopade Sure, the way I have shown. Or [this way](https://ideone.com/YWfjEt), with the regex defined as `var regex = """(?:http|ftp)s?://\S++.*?((?:http|ftp)s?://\S+)"""` and the return statement must be `return regexPattern.find(text.toString())?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)`

Comment: Hi @Wiktor,  Isn't there any way to output just the second Match ?
I have already tried your approach earlier but it outputs the whole text between the two URLs...

Comment: Insted of nth URL, Even if we can get Last URL would work for me, Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: I can't but repeat: **you will have to modify your code**. It is not PCRE or Onigmo, you have no `\K` operator support, and I doubt the constrained-width lookbehind will be that reliable... You might try `(?<=(?:http|ftp)s?://\S.*)(?:http|ftp)s?://\S+`, but I doubt it will work.

Comment: @VaibhavChopade To get the last match, all you need is `(?:http|ftp)s?://\S+(?!.*(?:http|ftp)s?://\S+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0MURdb/2).

Comment: @VaibhavChopade I see you removed the accepted mark. Do you want me to add this last solution to the answer?

Comment: Yes, I removed it because we have modified the actual problem statement. It does help me. But it isn't the solution to the original problem statement of Nth match. What should I do?  I thought removing the tick wont misguide others into

Comment: @VaibhavChopade My current solution is exactly how to get Nth match. The second one. You cannot get it with a pure Java regex, you MUST edit your code. That is all.